# Why do you have to read a pointer declaration backwords in C?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, syntax

In the C language, for simple cases, it seems that in order to read pointer declarations you have to proceed backwards. For example:

```
int n; 
int *p = &n; // p is a pointer to int
int *const np = &n; // np is a const pointer to int
int *const *npp = &np; //npp is a (non-const) pointer to const pointer to (non-const) int
```

Even though the proper way to parse type declarations is through what is called [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), wouldn't it be easier if the parsing rules were different so as to accommodate a reading of simple pointer declarations the other way?
For example:

```
int n;
*int p = &n; // p is a pointer to int
const *int np = &n; // np is a const pointer to int
*const *int npp = &np; // npp is a (non-const) pointer to const pointer to (non-const) int
```

So my question again: What were the principle behind such a design choice? What motivated the language designers to choose this particular way to declare types.

Comment: I think the only non-opinionated answer here would be "because it was historically defined like this".

Comment: There could always be someone to dig into the old documents to look for the rationale upon which this design was based, but I doubt it.

Comment: Think about `int *p, q;` vs "`*int p, q;`"

Comment: The non-opinionated answer is that you don't read backwards in general, only in simple cases. The canonical solution is the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: C declaration syntax is actually pretty complex - the type of an object or function is fully specified by a combination of *declaration specifiers* (type specifier, type qualifiers, storage class specifier) and a *declarator* (identifier, plus some combination of `*`, `()`, and `[]` operators).  Pointer-ness, array-ness, and function-ness are specified in the declarator, separate from the type specifier.  This allows you to create some fairly complex types in just a few keystrokes; downside is that these declarations get eye-stabby in a hurry.

Comment: *It would have been nice* if Ritchie had made the indirection operator postfix instead of unary - `T a[N]*[M]*;` is easier to read as "a is an array of pointers to an array of pointers to `T`" than `T *(*a[M])[N];`  We wouldn't have to bounce back and forth when reading the declaration.  But, he didn't.

Comment: My main point wasn't how it's read, more if there's a reason why it was defined as so. For example if it's necessary in complex constucts or if it's easier to implement in the compiler this way...

Comment: @elFreak: Ah.  In that case, it's because that's how B did it (which is because that's how BCPL did it, although with different operators).  A *lot* of C's weirdness can be traced back to B and BCPL.  You might find [this article](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.pdf) of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grammar aside. If I am not mistaken the idea behind:

```c
int **a;
```

is the following. You need to dereference a twice to get an int. This way const positions also start making sense.

```c
int * const * a;
```

This one would essentially mean that you need to dereference a once to get const pointer to int.

---

You may find it interesting and educational to read about C origins. (PDP, B, etc.)

Comment: The dereferencing syntax can be changed too. If we start changing things... So justifying one syntax by another is not really a way.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. This is how I see it. C has been created evolutionary rather than revolutionary, hence it borrowed some grammar from it's predecessors. There are several arguable grammar related decisions in my opinion (like function declaration syntax). Moreover C became adopted far earlier than it became standardized.  However as I see it the main goal by that time was to create a standard which would be close to existing implementations otherwise it would be an entirely different language and wouldn't be adopted. Afterwards it was all about backward compatibility.

Comment: Then we can ask about the predecessors the same? Where do we stop? This is why the question will be likely closed as opinion based.

Comment: @EugeneSh. While you may not like it, the creators of C did indeed design the languages from the expressions to the type declarations. With the guiding principle that the declaration of a variable should look similar to its use. Of course, they could have defined the dereferencing operator as a postfix operator just like the array subscript, but they didn't. Whatever they chose for the operator placement and precedence in expressions, fully defines the structure of the declarations.

Comment: @cmaster This requires a reference. If you have it, you can make a non-opinionated answer and I will gladly vote for reopening.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. You are correct. So I went to B language manual. Looks like it had * as a dereferencing operator. However B had no type notation. So I guess C somewhat adapted * to be used in type annotations.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Here is the reference. By Dennis M. Ritchie himself: https://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf2270/programmer/historien-om-C.pdf On page 7 you find that a) the pointer/array/function operators indeed predate C (from its typeless predecessors), and that b) he did indeed define the declaration syntax to match the expression syntax.

Comment: So it boils down to historical reasons, as stated in my comment to the question. Which reminds me the (arguable) [Horse ass](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~choset/horse_ass) story...

Answer (score 6):

> Why do you have to read a pointer declaration backwards in C?

In my opinion, it's difficult to say whether the declaration is *truly* backwards or not.

## For example...

I've noticed that the way I read the code in my head has changed over the last few years.

Consider the following code:

```
int *p;
```

How do you read this code in your head?

- **I used to read:** "p is a pointer to an int".
- **Now I read:** "an int pointer called p".

From using the language frequently, my brain has changed the way that I translate the source code to English. This allows me to understand the syntax without feeling like it's backwards.

To me, it feels *forwards*, although this is entirely subjective and will vary between people.

Moreover, there are probably many (spoken) languages where the source code translates nicely into a spoken sentence without having to change the ordering.

### Conclusion

Whether or not the declaration feels backwards can depend on...

- Your native language.
- How you translate the code to your native language.
- The size/complexity of the declaration.

Comment: I agree. I don't feel that the declaration is truly backwards. It makes perfect sense to me to think of the declaration as an integer pointer, rather than a pointer to an integer (although semantically they are the same). It's all syntax for the compiler anyways. Generally, pointers are all the same size (4 to 8 bytes). So in that sense, a pointer is a pointer. The compiler just uses the pointer type to validate usage elsewhere in the code.

Comment: How would you read the declaration `char* (*arr)[42]`? I'd definitely call this a `pointer to an array of 42 string pointers`, reading the declaration inside out...

Comment: @cmaster Hmm, that one's very tricky. I don't have a lot of experience reading complicated patterns like that. "pointer to an array of 42 string pointers" is how I read it (which indeed feels backwards). At least we still have https://cdecl.org/

Comment: What @cmaster example shows is that it's not a question of forward or backward reading. The proper way to read c types instead is from inside out, or even clockwise, spiral: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html There's also a "go right when you can, go left when you must" technique: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: @Tarc Yeah, the syntax can get out of control quite quickly. My answer only works for very small cases. The spiral trick is fantastic.

Comment: @byxor, "out of control" describes well I guess the situation :) From time to time I found myself in the need to study again how to properly read C type declarions.

Comment: @cmaster: Nitpicking: "*pointer to an array of 42*" **char** "*pointers*"! ;-)